# Java - JList setCellRenderer doesn't update after add or remove element

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

I'm new in Java, using `JList` with `DefaultListModel` and `getListCellRendererComponent` , should we set cell rendering every time we add or remove element in `JList`? Sorry for my English hope you understand my question.

Here is the code:

```
private JList <Detail>' createListdetail(String s) {

        model = new DefaultListModel<>();

        try {
            DbConnection.connDB();
             PreparedStatement  psm=DbConnection.getCon().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM produit WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[designation]) LIKE ?+'%'");
             psm.setString(1, s);
             rs=psm.executeQuery();

             while (rs.next()) {
                 model.addElement(new Detail(rs.getString(1).trim(), rs.getString(3).trim(),"Réf: "+rs.getString(2).trim(), rs.getString(6)));
             }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        list = new JList<Detail>(model);
        list.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
        list.setCellRenderer(new Produitdetail());
        validate();
        repaint();
        return list;

    }
```

And for cell renderer:

```
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Detail> list, Detail detail, int arg2, boolean isselected,
            boolean hasfocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        txtdesignation.setText(detail.getDesign());
        txtpa.setText(detail.getDernierPA());
        txtquantite.setText(detail.getQuantite());
        txtid.setText(detail.getId());
        return this;
    }
```

And third class detail for setter and getter; the first time I run everything its okay but how to add or remove and get the same renderer?

Comment: No. If the model is setup correctly, it will generate appropriate notifications, to which the `JList` will subscribe to when the model is applied, and will be updated automatically

Comment: Sorry, but no, I don't understand. Write a complete minimal example illustrating what you want to ask. Normally, just doing that should answer your question.

Comment: Could you please update your question to provide a complete, minimal, and verifiable example? Here's the community guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve